# Laravel 5.3. ReflectionException in Container.php line 809

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have been searching for solution but unsuccessfully.

I am trying to make activation mail feature for my registration by following these steps: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-email-verification-with-activation-code

-after adding/editing my project i get this error after trying to access **localhost/login** http://prntscr.com/dnveaf

this is my web route file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('user/activation/{token}', 'Auth\LoginController@activateUser')->name('user.activate');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

other code is same as code provided in first link.
I have no idea why it is trying to access 
*Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ActivationService*

Does anyone has idea what should I do?

Comment: fired `composer dump-autoload` yet?

Comment: @BagusTesa i tryed but nothing changes :/

Comment: ah, just realized, did you `use App\ActivationService` in your code that uses the `ActivationService` (`LoginController`)? -- you had to put the `use App\ActivationService` before `class LoginController{` line. if this fixes your problem, then it's a namespacing problem -- like an address to specify the class.

Comment: @BagusTesa ty man it works, i have lost 10 hours of my life with this..

Comment: no prob, glad it worked.